# How to show that $f : {}^\ast \Bbb R \to {}^\ast \Bbb R$ is bounded, if it obtains a limited value everywhere?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

Let $f :  {}^\ast \Bbb R \to  {}^\ast \Bbb R$. For all $x \in  {}^\ast \Bbb R $, there exists $y \in \Bbb R $ such that $f(x) \leq y$. How to show that there exists  $r \in \Bbb R$, such that for all $z \in  {}^\ast \Bbb R$  we have $f(z) \leq r$?

I know this can be shown by a direct application of the dual form of [idealization principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_set_theory#I%3a_Idealisation). Is there any other way to show this, say, using ultrapower construction?

Moreover, if $f$ is continuous, is it true that $f$ necessarily obtain a maximal value?

Comment: what do you mean by $^\ast\mathbb R$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number

Comment: If you write `$a ^\ast b$`, the asterisk will be a superscript on the $a$; TeX doesn't pay attention to spaces in math mode. You need to put an empty group to get it to show up where you want: `$a {}^\ast b$`.

Comment: To get from $\forall x\in {}^\ast\mathbb R\colon \exists y\in\mathbb R\colon f(x)\le y$ to $\forall z\in {}^\ast\mathbb R\colon \exists r\in\mathbb R\colon f(z)\le r$ takes only a change in variable.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Thank you.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Terribly sorry! I hope now it's been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our goal is to prove the statement

$$ (\forall z \in {}^{*}\Bbb{R} ) (\exists r \in \Bbb{R}) ( f(z) \leq r ) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (\exists r \in \Bbb{R})(\forall z\in {}^{*} \Bbb{R})( f(z) \leq r). $$

We prove the contrapositive:

$$ (\forall r \in \Bbb{R})(\exists z\in {}^{*} \Bbb{R})( f(z) > r) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (\exists z \in {}^{*}\Bbb{R} ) (\forall r \in \Bbb{R}) ( f(z) > r ). $$

Assume that for any $r \in \Bbb{R}$, there exists $z \in {}^{*}\Bbb{R} $ such that $f(z) > r$. For each fixed $r \in \Bbb{R}$, applying the transfer principle, we have

$$(\exists z \in {}^{*}\Bbb{R})( f(z) > r ) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (\exists z \in \Bbb{R})( f(z) > r ). $$

Thus we have

$$ (\forall r \in \Bbb{R})(\exists z \in \Bbb{R})( f(z) > r ). $$

Passing to the transfer principle, we obtain

$$ (\forall r \in {}^{*}\Bbb{R})(\exists z \in {}^{*}\Bbb{R})( f(z) > r ). $$

In particular, for a given infinitely large $R \in {}^{*}\Bbb{R}$, we have $f(z) > R$ for some $z \in {}^{*}\Bbb{R}$. This can be rephrased as

$$ (\exists z \in {}^{*}\Bbb{R} ) (\forall r \in \Bbb{R}) ( f(z) > r ). $$

This is exactly what we wanted, and hence the proof is completed.

To show that $f$ may fail to achieve its maximum, we consider the function

$$ f(x) = \frac{|x| + 1}{|x| + 2}. $$

It is clear that for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$ we have $f(x) < 1$ while for each $r < 1$ there exists $x \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x) > r$. This can be transferred into the corresponding statement in the hyperreal field, and thus $f(x)$ has no maximum on $\Bbb{R}^{*}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reference.

Answer (score 2):

The set of upper bounds for the function contains all unlimited numbers.  Therefore by the underspill principle, it must contain a finite number, as well.

Of course, this is in the assumption that the function is internal.  Otherwise there are obvious counterexamples.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. What is underflow principle? I check the indexes of Alain Robert's textbook, Hurd & Loeb's and google it, but I can't find anything useful.

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace, you may refer to the [*Lectures on the Hyperreals*](http://books.google.co.kr/books/about/Lectures_on_the_hyperreals.html?id=TII-PX_OdloC&redir_esc=y) by Robert Goldblatt.

Comment: To paraphrase the answer, the set of upper bounds contains all the unlimited numbers.  But the set of all unlimited numbers is not internal.  Therefore the set of all upper bounds, being an internal set, necessarily contains a limited number, as well.

Comment: I meant "underspill", not "underflow".